# Renaming an outlet in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I accidentally misspelled one of the outlet's in my view controller and ran into a few issues. When I manually try to correct the typo I get stopped at runtime within `AppDelegate` I'm shown the message,

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

which highlights the beginning of the code block:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  ...
}
```

I've found that to fix this issue in Objective-C you would right-click the outlet's original name and "Refactor => Rename" but unfortunately I get the message:

> Xcode can only refactor C and Objective-C code

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var billTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var tipRateSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    @IBOutlet weak var tiLabel: UILabel! // Variable name should be "tipLabel"

    @IBAction func calculateTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        var userInput = billTextField.text as NSString
        var totalBill: Float = userInput.floatValue
        var index: Int = tipRateSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        var tipRate: Float = 0.15

        if index == 0 {
            tipRate == 0.15
        } else if index == 1 {
            tipRate = 0.20
        } else {
            tipRate = 0.25
        }

        var tip: Float = totalBill * tipRate

        tipLabel.text = "$\(tip)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting up for the Refactor > Rename trick in Objective-C. Big help for me :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**EDIT**: Since Xcode9, there's a *refactor function*; the new good method is the one [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46047765/1392046)

---

Since Xcode 6, you can look for your outlet names directly in the Find navigator (`Cmd+3`), it shows occurrences in your code and **in your xibs and storyboards**. It also works with actions.

Just search the name in the Find navigator.

[image]

You can see that the second result is a reference in a storyboard. You can replace one by one by clicking on each result and press *Replace*, or you can directly *Replace All* if you are sure you don't break anything.

Answer (score 21):

## Refactor > Rename...

Xcode 9 had many editor improvements including a feature that changes an outlet/action name in the code and storyboard from one place.

In the example Swift code below, right click on `btnRequestCode`, from the popup menu select **"Refactor > Rename..."**, change the outlet/action name and Xcode changes it in the Storyboard also.

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnRequestCode: UIButton!
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With swift this kind of refactor doesn't work yet. You have to change the name of the outlet, and then delete and reset the connection in the interface builder.

**Updated:**
[image]

Right click the IBOutlet that you want to rename, delete reference outlet, and then reassign it, but you don't have to do anything with your code.

Comment: Is there anything I need to do besides removing the referencing outlet? I deleted the two lines of code that reference the outlet and the above but still get halted.

Comment: It turns out that I also had to uncheck the `Toggle global breakpoint state` to get it to run again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like to fix situations like this by just opening the Storyboard as source code and editing the XML-like tags.

Right click the .storyboard file and choose "Open As". Search for the old outlet (or action/method) name that is still set in the storyboard but which no longer matches the renamed method/outlet object in the View Controller. Edit the Xml tag in the storyboard to give it the new name of your outlet or action in the view controller.